# Any way to find all possible kwargs for a function in python from cli?

Tags: python, function, keyword-argument, function-signature

Is there a way to discover the potential keyword arguments for a function in python from the command line? without looking at the source or docs. Sometimes the source is to c lib even that isn't visible

Comment: `help(whatever_function)`?

Comment: By definition every possible key value pair is a potential keyword argument if you use kwargs

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `inspect` module. In 3.3+, this is easy by using [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature)

```
import inspect

def foo(bar=None, baz=None):
    pass

>>> print(inspect.signature(foo))
(bar=None, baz=None)
```

Immediately underneath the linked doc is an [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Parameter) that pulls out only the names of the keyword-only arguments, which may be worth reading too!

Of course if you're looking to deep inspect the source code to try and find anything that is pulled out of a `**kwargs` argument, you're probably out of luck. Something like:

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    if kwargs.get("isawesome"):
        print("Dang you're awesome")

>>> some_magic(foo)
isawesome
```

is probably going to be hard to find.

Comment: Note also that this won't work for all builtin functions written in C, which don't usually have named arguments at all: E.g., try `inspect.signature(sum)` and you'll get an error.

Comment: A good point! I don't know if there's any way to inspect the signature of a function that's not written in Python.

Answer (score 0):

For a function 'myfunc' use this:

```
myfunc.__code__.co_varnames
```